# How to write tests for validation?

Tags: java, validation, junit

Let's say you have a request class defined like this:

```
public class CreateUserRequest {
  @NotNull
  @Pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  @Size(min = 6, max = 16)
  public String userName;

  @NotNull
  @Pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  @Size(min = 8, max = 32)
  public String password;

  @NotNull
  @Pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$")
  @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
  public String fullName;      
}
```

How do you write tests for constraints?
Do you write these tests at all?

**Minor update**

It's not about constraints I'm using in this example. It's about testing/not testing *whatever* constraints you have.

Comment: 1) Yes, I'd certainly write tests.  2) Are you sure you want to exclude digits from fullName?  3) Is there anything else that might fail validation that a user might legitimately try to enter?  A "space" or "apostrophe", for example?

Comment: Exact constraints used in the example code doesn't really matter. I'm wondering whether there's a common way to test whether constraint are somewhat OK or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate validator allows validating individual fields, so for this case one of the possible solutions is to write tests for `userName`, `password` and `fullName`. This approach is pretty silly though, you may check this for better approach: [Using same constraints in multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425797/using-same-constraints-in-multiple-classes).