# Using same constraints in multiple classes

Tags: java, validation

Pretend you have a class like this one:

```
public class CreateUserRequest {
  ...
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 16)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  private final String userName;
  ...
}
```

What we have here is a field "userName" that has some constraints, so that some values are OK and some are not. You also have a class `EditUserRequest`. You user `userName` as user identifier, so you're going to have this field in `EditUserRequest` for sure:

```
public class EditUserRequest {
  ...
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 16)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  private final String userName;
  ...
}
```

And for sure you'd like to be able to delete users:

```
public class DeleteUserRequest {
  ...
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 16)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  private final String userName;
  ...
}
```

All these classes have a field "userName" with absolutely similar meaning and similar constraints. One day you decide that you also want to allow more symbols to be used in `userName`s. So, you have to manually fix all these 3 classes.

## Solution #1

Make a base class for all these requests:

```
public abstract AbstractUserRequest {
  ...
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 16)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  private final String userName;
  ...  
}

public class CreateUserRequest extends AbstractUserRequest {
  ... // OK, we have userName here
}
```

**Pros**:

- You now only have to fix the constraints once
- Creating new types of requests is pretty trivial, you just subclass `AbstractUserRequest` and it works.

**Cons**:

- In case you need `userName` somewhere else, you'll have to have a subclass of `AbstractUserRequest` (example: `CreateUserGroupRequest` which requires a list of `userName`s, for sure you want to validate them first)
- Not excactly sure how to test this properly

## Solution #2

Make separate classes for each type of field, so that when you talk about "user name", you know it's not just a `String`, it's a constrained `String`:

```
public class UserNameField {
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 16)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
  private final String value;
  ...
}

public class CreateUserRequest {
  ...
  private UserNameField userName;
  ...
}
```

**Pros**:

- In case user name constraints change, you'll only have to fix it once
- You have a simple class which is easy to test

**Cons**:

- Feels like overkill (?)

## Solution #3 (update)

Hibernate validator allows constraint composition, so that you can give a name for a group of constraints:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4, max = 16)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface UserName {
  String message() default "{com.loki2302.constraints.username}";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
...
public class CreateUserRequest {
  ...
  @UserName
  private final String userName;
  ...
}
```

**Pros:**

- Simple yet powerful approach
- Easy to use (no extra abstractions)
- Easy to test

**Cons:**

- None probably?

What is the common approach here? Does the **Solution #2** look fine? How do **you** do it?

Comment: It's time to preprocess the file with gcc before compiling, or your solution 2 looks OK in term of design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely go for **Solution #2**. As you demonstrated above, you may want to use `UserNameField` in a class that isn't a request, which makes the `AbstractRequest` class feel like a slightly worse alternative.
Creating a class to avoid duplicate code and get all logic in the same place sounds like an excellent idea to me, and not overkill at all.

**[EDIT after addition of Solution #3]**
**Solution #3** looks like a very nice variation of **Solution #2**. I can't really decide which one I like more, they both do a fine job of encapsulating the logic.

Comment: +1 this is a perfect example of using a [value object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject) to encapsulate constraints and related functionality.

Comment: @Keppil: me too, basically :-) Looks like #3 is better since it does the same that #2 does and it doesn't add a level of indirection. But I agree, #2 and #3 are very similar.

Comment: @Loki2302: You might be right there. Go for that one then if it feels better.